# Setting up a Custom Domain for a Page (just like Blogger)

Tags: php, mysql, dns

In my website, people have profiles, but they wanted to have their custom domain point to their profile page, i.e.:

```
http://www.profilepgaes.com/jhonsmith
```

Custom domain:

```
http://www.jhonsmith.com
```

**What's the best way to accomplish this task?**

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a CNAME record.

http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=58317

Answer (score 0):

easy!

Go into the dns settings, in there create a new record. Should be option for cname. From there add it with the value ghs.google.com. Its jamziee here btw.